# measuring resistance on hv transformer

Tags: transformer, resistance, multimeter, instrumentation

I need to verify the resistance on a HV transformer that receives 208v single phase through terminal 1 and 2, or 240v through terminal 1 and 3 and delivers 4000v through terminal 4. As per the specifications, the resistance between t1 and t2 needs to be somewhere between 0.8-1.1 ohms(obvious the transformer has to be completely disconnected of power for the test). i tried a few clamp multi testers and none seemed to deliver a proper reading, some take a little long to come to a reading and oscillate up and down, bottom line is, i almost never have a proper reading.
question, what multi tester (preferable a clamp style, because i need it for other applications) would be the proper one for the call.
thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Bulky inductiors are hard to measure with auto-ranging meters.

For measurement of such a low resistance a Kelvin measurement is reccomended.

This means applying a known current through two probes and measuring the voltage through two others.

Answer (score 1):

You need to measure DC resistance, right?
If so, it's a good idea to suppress inductance of the coil. To acheive this, short circuit secondary winding while measuring resistance of primary.